# RealURL not working anymore after switching to HTTPS

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

I have switched a website (Typo3 8.7.20, RealURL 2.4.0) to HTTPS. Since then, URLS (e.g. /en or /service) are resulting in 404 errors. When RealURL is off, everything works fine. RealURL is in autoconfiguration and has worked flawlessly.

This is part of the setup relevant:

```
config {
  prefixLocalAnchors = all
  doctype = xhtml_trans
  baseURL =
  absRefPrefix = auto
  absRelPath = /
  tx_realurl_enable = 1
  prefixLocalAnchors = all
```

I have already deleted all caches, the RealURL configuration (to re-generate) and even uninstalled the extension and db tables and re-installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just setting `config.baseURL=https://www.yourdomainhere.com/` should work.

Comment: Please do not use config.baseURL anymore. Using config.absRefPrefix is correct.

Comment: Even setting absRefPrefix to https://... does not help.

Comment: Use `absRefPrefix = /` with realurl. It does not handle auto well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark maybe on your https vhost apache configuration is missing the AllowOverride Configuration for the ssl vhost.

In this case the .htaccess file will not be parsed and the nessesary rewrite rules for realurl will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks but I have checked that and AllowOverride is set.

Comment: OK, although it was set, the server did not read the directive properly (my mistake). Fixed it and now it is working fine. Thank you.